# PHP: Reason to not to Inject object

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I know Dependency Injection can be beneficial but I wanted to see if there were cases when it was not necessary.  For example, I have an app class that does have di for the constructor but I have a dispatcher class that I don't think needs to be injected because it just performs a simple loadController method.  It doesn't change.

```
 //front controller
 $request = new Request();
 $routetable = new Routetable();
 $router = new Router($request, $routetable);
 $session = new Session();
 $app = new App($request, $router, $session);
 $app->run();
```

App Class

```
 //app class
 class app {
     ...
        public function run(){
             $dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
             $dispatcher->loadcontroller($this->router); 
             //gets controller and method from router.
        } 
     }
}
```